# hadoop windows (work ok) linux java heap space

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, heap-memory

Here is my problem:
First of all I'm working with hadoop and a single node configuration
I'm developing an application and I made just one map function, in this map function I call like 10 functions,
the application reads from a csv file and process a certain column, I already made the jar file and everything so when I run this app with a csv with 4000 rows on windows (windows 7) (using cygwin) on a 4 GB RAM machine, the application works fine, but when I run it on linux- ubuntu on a 2 GB RAM machine, it process some rows but then it throws a "Java heap space" error, or sometimes the thread is killed.

For the linux:
I already tried to change the hadoop export HEAP_SIZE and also the Xmx and Xms parameters on the app and it made some difference but not too much, the error stills happening...

Do you know why it s happening?  its because the 4GB and 2GB of RAM difference between machines?

Comment: oh well, there are so many places to start looking into, so it'll be highly presumptuous to nail it on the RAM difference. why don't you try running VisualVM [packaged free with the JDK for both linux & Win]. take some memory stack dumps to see how the application behaves. personally, i don't think reading 4000 lines is a big thing for 2 gigs of RAM!

Comment: 2GB RAM machine can easily handle 4000 rows. I would say verify your 10 functions for any possible memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I ran into with a mapper is if you call/use functions/objects that start their own threads from within the `map` function, this can easily create enough threads to use all the heap space for that JVM.
Each mapper will have the `setup` and `cleanup` function called once. In my situation I was able to process and put into an `ArrayList` all my data, then do the additional processing I needed in the `cleanup` function.